# Build an iOS like Transition on an Activity Change

Tags: java, android, xml

So, I'm trying to build a transition between two Activities in my Android App, that looks similar to the transitions in iOS Apps. And my "Going in Transition" works perfectly fine, the way I want it to work, the new layout slides over the old one, while the old one moves just a bit to the left. But now I'm stuck with the reverse transition, going back to my first layout, cause I want it to look exactly like the first transition, but just reversed, which I'm not able to achieve, cause Android automatically layers the moving in transition on top of the moving out transition, as you can see in the attached gif.

So I would have two ideas, to work around that problem. Is there either a possibility to change the layers of the transition? If not, it would be also possible to animate a moving mask ok my moving in transition. But for neither of these possibilities, I know how to implement them.

[image]

My current code:

I just call the animations on the OnCreate of my two activities:

OnCreate of my Main Menu:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_left);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

On Create of my Settings:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_right);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
}
```

And my xml files:
slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:fromXDelta="-30%p"
android:toXDelta="0"

android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

slide-out-left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="100%p"

android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:fromXDelta="100%p"
android:toXDelta="0"

android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="-30%p"

android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

Comment: use   **overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_left);** when you pass intent for setting activity.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity

```
       private boolean isReverseAnimation = false;
           @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                isReverseAnimation = false;
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left,R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
//your other code
}

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            if (isReverseAnimation) {
                this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_right,
                        R.anim.anim_slide_out_right);

            }else{
                isReverseAnimation = true;
            }
        }
```

And Setting activity as it is.

Try and let me know if have any issue.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Well that doesnt really change anything, I cant see any difference :D

Comment: Do you finish your Setting activity?

Comment: Well but an onStop() Function could work... Let me try that! :D

Comment: Nope, I tried onStop() and onPause() but the activity I'm switching to is still always layered on top of the old one...

Comment: Well, it still works the same way as before, but not the way I want it to work... I'll try again this evening, but thanks a lot for your help anyway :)

Comment: @Miltesh Btw, I edited my question a bit. Probably it wasnt entirely clear what I'm trying to achieve?